# Azure Synapse Delta table

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I encountered a problem when I tried to modify a Synapse delta table from a Synapse Notebook. I used the ALTER TABLE command to add a new column to the table, and I verified that the column was created by using the DESCRIBE and SELECT commands. However, when I checked the Lake database in the Azure portal, I could not see the new column under the table properties. Also, the new column was missing from the sys.columns list.

[image]
I wonder why there is a discrepancy between the DESCRIBE and the portal views of the table, and how I can fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Provide the code you tried and output screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why there is a discrepancy between the DESCRIBE and the portal views of the table, and how I can fix it.

I tried it in my environment and faced similar issue with the lake database table when altering it from synapse.

The issue might cause when there is a delay in refresh of metadata. You can try below steps to resolve it:

- **Refresh the Metadata**: You can try run below command in Notebook to refresh the table metadata explicitly.

```sql
REFRESH TABLE <table_name>
```

[image]

- **Restart Synapse Workspace**: Sometimes, because of caching metadata is not getting refreshed you can first publish your notebook and then refresh the synapse workspace can trigger a metadata refresh.

**Now it's working for me:**

[image]